# Android getting error in sqlite database class

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting this java runtime exception and i have checked my query as well. All seem to b right. i am just not understanding where i am going wrong
I have checked it and dint find anything wrong. Please help me
    This is my logcat

```
 07-05 10:59:38.204 12209-12209/com.example.user.easytodolist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.user.easytodolist, PID: 12209
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.easytodolist/com.example.user.easytodolist.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEtasks": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEtasks(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, titleTEXT NOT NULL);
                                                                                   #################################################################
                                                                                   Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                                                                                   Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                                                                                    (near "TABLEtasks": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEtasks(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, titleTEXT NOT NULL);)
                                                                                   #################################################################
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                                    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEtasks": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEtasks(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, titleTEXT NOT NULL);
                                                                                   #################################################################
                                                                                   Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                                                                                   Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                                                                                    (near "TABLEtasks": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEtasks(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, titleTEXT NOT NULL);)
                                                                                   #################################################################
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1000)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:565)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1838)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1769)
                                                                                       at com.example.user.easytodolist.db.TaskHelper.onCreate(TaskHelper.java:17)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
                                                                                       at com.example.user.easytodolist.MainActivity.updateUI(MainActivity.java:84)
                                                                                       at com.example.user.easytodolist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
                                                                                        ... 9 more
```

This is my **MainActivity**.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.user.easytodolist.db.Task;
import com.example.user.easytodolist.db.TaskHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private TaskHelper mHelper;
    private ListView mTaskListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mHelper = new TaskHelper(this);
        mTaskListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_todo);
        updateUI();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.action_add_task:
                    final EditText taskEditTask = new EditText(this);
                    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("New Task")
                    .setMessage("Add a New Task")
                    .setView(taskEditTask)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            String task = String.valueOf(taskEditTask.getText());
                            SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                           values.put(com.example.user.easytodolist.db.Task.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE,task);
                           db.insertWithOnConflict(Task.TaskEntry.TABLE,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                            db.close();
                            updateUI();
                        }
                    })
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                            .create();
                    dialog.show();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);



            }
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
                SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(Task.TaskEntry.TABLE,
                new String[]{Task.TaskEntry._ID, Task.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE} ,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(Task.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
            taskList.add(cursor.getString(index));
        }

        if(mAdapter == null){
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_todo,R.id.task_title,taskList);
            mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else{
            mAdapter.clear();
            mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }


    public void deleteTask(View view){
        View parent = (View) view.getParent();
        TextView taskTextView  = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
        String task = String.valueOf(taskTextView.getText());
        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(Task.TaskEntry.TABLE, Task.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + "= ?", new String[] {task});
        db.close();
        updateUI();

    }
}
```

My TaskHelperclass

```
package com.example.user.easytodolist.db;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class TaskHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public TaskHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,Task.DB_NAME,null,Task.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + Task.TaskEntry.TABLE + " ( " +
                                              Task.TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                                              Task.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Task.TaskEntry.TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

And Task Class

```
package com.example.user.easytodolist.db;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class Task {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "com.example.user.easytodolist.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public class TaskEntry implements BaseColumns{
        public static final String TABLE= "tasks";
        public static final String COL_TASK_TITLE = "title";
    }
}
```

Comment: `i have checked my query as well` looks like you didn't check careful enough. you are missing space in your SQL

Comment: Just uninstall app from emulator or device and then try again to install with run application.

Comment: @NitinPatel uninstalling the app and running it again worked!!.. Thanks dude!

Comment: @shashankverma Just select previous comment as useful if you get really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLEtasks(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, titleTEXT NOT NULL);
```

This query should be

```
CREATE TABLE tasks(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT NOT NULL);
```

You missed the spaces

Comment: in the taskhelper @Abdullah?

Comment: What do you mean in the task helper? You should use this into the onCreate method inside the class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: Thanks for the help @Abdullah Tellioglu!  It  worked. My query was correct I had to just uninstall and run it again! Thanks again